# Glass rendering black in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, glass

Still very fresh to Blender. I need the glass window to be transparent in this scene, as I have a light source outside and the light should come through the window.

The window of the cupboard in the corner of the room uses the same material and it works, the glass is clear and transparent. But not with the main window.

Any idea on what the issue might be? I can provide you with any further information if needed.

[image: Picture of the room]

[image: Picture of the light source]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

my node set up for transparency in cycles. hope this helps

Comment: I added a solidify mod and it removed the refractions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changing nodes did nothing for me. What solved my problem was simply removing the window object and redoing it again.

Nevertheless, I appreciate your assistance.